# Laravel 5.7 CORB blocked issue

Tags: php, laravel, cross-origin-read-blocking

Hey there I'm getting the error:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response ... with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I have tried a lot of fixes found here on stackoverflow, but nothing fixed the issue.

Here's where I'm currently at:

I have installed barryvdh/laravel-cors with the follow config:

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedOriginsPatterns' => ['*'],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
'exposedHeaders' => [],
'maxAge' => 0,
```

I'm loading the middleware in my controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('cors');
}
public function code($id)
{
    $domain = \App\Domain::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('code',compact('domain'));
}
```

and it is defined in my Kernel.php

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

This is the curl reponse I get if I try from the terminal

```
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.15.5
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
cache-control: no-cache, private
date: Mon, 05 Aug 2019 10:06:08 GMT
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Im05MnZ5K2IwS3Q3SnhQSDZ2a3lNMkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoia0RSZ1o2XC9IYkNTS3J2YlI2SWtrZUxXa2JSUThUcUhoR2FqSmN1aTYwZEpxQmp4ak5ORGJiRlQwdFJPNERlM0kiLCJtYWMiOiI2ZGJmMjFiMWM2OWQ0MDdkMDdjNWI5NTMyNGMzOTFhMmU4NGFiMjc2Zjg3NjExMjU0ZGM1M2MwODRiODI0MzZmIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 05-Aug-2019 12:06:08 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
set-cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InZGekJCV2VUbEd0OFdpVWdzd0pzcXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC9jb1JTTnJGV1FlNDhiVzB5dE43NnZCdHlaYlR6ZU82Wk1BclR5bWtVbUpZYWtGRTRGNDF3OEMrZ3J6eDJ1WFgiLCJtYWMiOiIwODE3YTY5NzZlNmQ2NTYzZjhhZWFkY2VjZTYxNGY2NmI1MDk4ZWM5MGE2Y2Q5MWI3N2UzMjEzMGFhNDVmZjA0In0%3D; expires=Mon, 05-Aug-2019 12:06:08 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
```

This is how I try to load the page

```
function loadContent(url)
{
   var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  loadContent("https://xx.com/this/{{$domain->id}}")
})
```

And my route is:

```
Route::get('/this/{id}', 'ThisController@code');
```

This is how I'm load the javascript file from a external site:

```
<!-- code --><div id="content"></div><script src="https://thissite.com/1"></script><!-- End code -->
```

Comment: **Read the error message carefully**. It says **CORB** not **CORS**

Comment: What does the response body look like?

Comment: Ah yeah, I noticed it said CORB, but if I search about it, it will come up with stuff related to CORS. Anyway the reponse body is here: https://screencast.com/t/FUocP52CCb

Comment: And this is the reponse from the site it's trying to load: https://screencast.com/t/7MaT4m57h

Comment: I have added the code block I use to load the javascript file from my server, I think the way I'm doing it gives me trouble, I have tried write the javascript file on my site instead of included it with "script", and this works. But I need to do it the otherway around as it will be customers who will load the javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the header:

'Content-Typet' to 'application/javascript' solved this.